# Unity NetworkTransform: synchronize two player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client-server, multiplayer

I am trying to develop an online pong. i am using masterserver.
I want my game to synchronize two player on the server, so i check:
 when ones is localplayer, it synchronize movement on server;
 when other player sync on server, it should show movement on other client.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Movement : NetworkBehaviour {

  private Vector2 speedx = new Vector2(3,0);
  private float lastSynchronizationTime = 0f;
  private float syncDelay = 0f;
  private float syncTime = 0f;
  private Vector2 syncStartPosition = Vector2.zero;
  private Vector2 syncEndPosition = Vector2.zero;

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
     if (isLocalPlayer)
     {
         InputMovement();
     }
    else
     {
         SyncedMovement();
     }
  }

  private void SyncedMovement()
  {
    syncTime += Time.deltaTime;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = Vector2.Lerp(syncStartPosition, syncEndPosition, syncTime / syncDelay);
  }

  void InputMovement()
  {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position + speedx * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position - speedx * Time.deltaTime);
  }

  void OnSerializeNetworkView(BitStream stream, NetworkMessageInfo info)
  {
    Vector3 syncPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 syncVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    if (stream.isWriting)
    {
        syncPosition = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;
        stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);
        syncVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
        stream.Serialize(ref syncVelocity);
    }
    else
    {
        stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);
        stream.Serialize(ref syncVelocity);

        syncTime = 0f;
        syncDelay = Time.time - lastSynchronizationTime;
        lastSynchronizationTime = Time.time;

        syncEndPosition = syncPosition + syncVelocity * syncDelay;
        syncStartPosition = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position;
        Debug.Log("syncstart");
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me synching two players?
edit:
when i start server, player of server spawn, but i can't move it.
when i start client, player of client spawn on server but player of server doesn't show in client window. i can't move both client and server.

Comment: Hi. Could you please edit your question and add some details? What is the problem? Is there any error message?

Comment: On top of @CydrickT comment, do all physics in FixedUpdate, not Update...

Comment: done. i have tried FixedUpdate and Update, it doesn't works in every case.

Comment: you dont assign syncPosition and syncVelocity to rigidbody in else statement.

Comment: do what @BarışÇırıka says!

Comment: @Joe Are there any problem?

Comment: no, I meant "Baris is correct: do what he says!"   :)

Comment: Sorry. I missunderstood you.

Comment: It doesn't enter in the if

Comment: NetworkBehaviour is Unity3d UNET, OnSerializeNetworkView is old Unity3d Networking. They don't mix.